# Download or display XML file in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, html, internet-explorer, data-uri

I have a simple javascript application that lets the user generate some XML and then save it as a file. However I can't get the saving to work in IE.

Currently I am using the `data-uri` method as exemplified in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceh6aaop/). But this does not work in IE because it [does not support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) `data-uri` for `application/xml`. What would be another method or workaround (client-only) to let the user easily save an xml string (or dom node) as a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer was given by Mr Anonymous in the comment.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  var xml = $("textarea").text();
  if(window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob){
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.msSaveBlob( new Blob([xml], {type:'application/xml'}), "myfile.xml" )
  } else {
    $(this).attr("href", "data:application/xml," + encodeURIComponent(xml));      
  }
});
```